# C++ client/server application with single messages and broadcast

Tags: c++, client-server, qt5

I am trying to write a simple client-server application where a client can send or broadcast a message to one or all clients in the network. The server stores all IP addresses that are connected to it, and broadcasts a new IP if a new client connects itself.

I'm not quite sure how to implement the sending of a single message to another client. Would I just have to send a TCP message to the server and put the desired recipient as data in the TCP layer which is then extracted by the server so it knows where to send it?

I also want to add encryption to the messages which would then no longer allow the server to read the data, so I'm not sure how to solve that!?

I am using c++ and Qt5 for the implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm not quite sure how to implement the sending of a single message to
>   another client. Would I just have to send a TCP message to the server
>   and put the desired recipient as data in the TCP layer which is then
>   extracted by the server so it knows where to send it?

In an ideal world, the clients could talk to each other directly, since they could find out the IP addresses of the other clients from the server (either via its broadcast or by requesting a list of IP addresses from the server).  If all of your clients are running on the same LAN, that can work well.

Assuming you want your system to run on the general Internet, however, that won't work so well, since many/most clients will be behind various firewalls and so they won't accept incoming TCP connections.  (There are some [ways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_hole_punching) around that, but they require a very advanced understanding of how TCP works, and even then they only work in certain situations, so I don't recommend attempting them in a first project)

Therefore, for a reliable client->client messaging mechanism, your best bet is indeed to have the sending client send the message to the server, along with some short header that tells the server which other client(s)  the message ought to be forwarded to.  My [own](http://www.lcscanada.com/muscle/index.html) client/server messaging system works along these lines, and I've found it to work well.

> I also want to add encryption to the messages which would then no
>   longer allow the server to read the data, so I'm not sure how to solve
>   that!?

Don't worry about adding encryption until you've got the basic non-encrypted functionality working first, since encryption will make things much more difficult to debug.  That said, it's perfectly possible to pass encrypted/opaque data to the server, as long as the aforementioned header data (which tells the server where to forward the message to) is not encrypted (since the server will need to be able to read the header to know what to do with the encrypted data).  The trickier part will be when the receiving client gets the forwarded data from the server -- how will the receiving client know how to decrypt it?  You'll need some external mechanism for clients to share keys (either symmetric keys or public/private keypairs), since if you sent the encryption keys themselves through the server, there wouldn't be much point in encrypting anything (since the server could retain a copy of any keys it forwarded, and use them to decrypt, if it wanted to)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was thinking about using PGP, when a client connects itself to the network it asks for the public keys and sends its own to the existing clients in the network. Therefore the server does not have to store any data but only the clients. Any thoughts about that?

Comment: Keep in mind that if you're not going to trust the server, then you have to consider the possibility that an evil server might do things like forward a fake public key to the destination client instead of the real one, etc.  Trying to prevent man-in-the-middle attacks is difficult unless at least some part of your communication doesn't go through the untrusted server.